# Написание обработчика прерывания

Tags: c, unix

Возникла следующая идея: я имею несколько открытых дескрипторов и ассоциированных с ними объектов FILE соответственно. Ввод соответственно буферизированный. Является ли хорошей идеей и вообще, есть ли такая возможность написать свой обработчик прерывания и зарегать его в ядре, который будет делать следующее: делает у всех FILE процесса flush. Т.е. таким образом мы сделаем одно обращение к ядру и за это обращение вычитаем из всех буферов, которые есть - profit.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду написать как-то иначе, по-своему эту функцию: http://www.c-cpp.ru/content/flushall ? Думаете, она будет более эффективной?

Comment: Нет нет. Я вот что узнал: когда я устанавливаю устройство какое то, то я устанавливаю драйвер. В процессе этой установки, регистрируется обработчик прерывания этого устройства в ядре. Т.е. например процесс хочет напечатать на принтере, вызывается обработчик прерывания этого принтера, который и занимается этим делом.

Comment: В идеале я хочу сделать так: написать обработчик прерывания, зарегать его в ядре, и пользоваться им из своих процессов. Т.е. буду генерить из процесса прерывание, на которое будет вызываться мой написанный обработчик и делать свои дела

Comment: Например генерить прерывание из кода так: callMyHandler(FILE** pf).  Здесь я делаю системный вызов, который обработает мой обработчик. В процессе работы обработчик сделает flush из всех объектов FILE* . Выигрыш в том, что я солью инфу из всех буферов во все файлы за один системный вызов

Comment: Я не знаю что это за функция: flushall)) мне просто интересно было бы самому повозиться с реализацией такой темы, и поэтому хочу узнать, позволит ли мне ос сделать то что я хочу

Comment: Ну, функция как раз выполняет сброс буферов всех открытых файлов. Но, конечно, никто не отменял принцип "зачем просто, если можно сложно" :)

Comment: @Semerkin, лучше продолжай разбираться, на вопрос сложно ответить что-то вменяемое, ибо большинство фраз звучат абсурдно или не корректно... В чём именно ты заблуждаешься сказать сложно, но думаю, что а) ты путаешь программные и аппаратные прерывания; б) не понимаешь, что из себя представляют Си'шные потоки ввода-вывода; в) в частности не понимаешь/не знаешь, что io в них буферизирован в пространстве пользователся; г) ⇒ путаешь `fflush ()` и `fsync ()`. д) имеешь крайне смутное понятия о таких абстракциях как «системный вызов», «пространство ядра», «пространство пользователя».

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> я хочу сделать так: написать обработчик прерывания, зарегать его в
>   ядре, и пользоваться им из своих процессов.

Тема очень большая и сложная. Для начала, рекомендую почитать:

1. "Драйверы Устройств Linux", 3-я редакция, by Jonathan Corbet, Alessandro Rubini, and Greg Kroah-Hartman (Есть перевод)
2. "Программирование модулей ядра Linux" Олег Цилюрик,

Именно в этих книгах рассказывается, как написать обработчик прерывания (драйвер), зарегистрировать его в ядре и пользоваться из пространства пользователя.